# JSON value with spaces

Tags: json, unity-game-engine

im developing on Unity and using [this](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/SimpleJSON) SimpleJSON library to read a JSON. So i do the following:

```
JSONNode datos = JSON.Parse (jsonString); 
for (int i = 0; i < datos["posts"].Count; i++) {
    string aux = datos ["posts"] [i] ["text"];
 }
```

So the aux string reads the value of the text but it deletes all the spaces of the text. So if i have "Hello, how are you?" on the JSON, i get "Hello,howareyou?" on the string.

Is there anyway of avoiding this to happen?

Thanks!

EDIT:

I get the jsonString like this:

```
string url = " ";
WWW www = new WWW (url);
yield return www;
string json = "";
if (www.error == null) {
    json = www.text;
    Processjson (json); 
}
```

Comment: I think that it is not the problem with the library. Can you provide more relevant code - how do you retrieve `jsonString` variable?

Comment: `unity` is wrong tag. maybe you mean `unity3d`?

Comment: I use SimpleJSON evry day, and it does not remove empty spaces. You need to do something with the string before parsing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two possible scenarios:

1. The most likely, the response from http server, was already with removed spaces in JSON strings or you removed it somewhere before parsing.
2. SimpleJSON does it when not naming the types explicty. What I mean is: you get string by this:

string aux = datos ["posts"] [i] ["text"]

but *maybe* you should do:

```
string aux = datos.AsObject ["posts"].AsArray [i].AsObject ["text"].Value;
```

Also try to parse to JSONObject:

```
JSONObject datos = JSON.Parse (jsonString).AsObject;
```